# Is there any way to customize the save button in window.print() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function in my webpage to save it as pdf so I'm using the window.print() in javascript. And I want to happen is to save it in my local storage www.sample.com/storage/sample-file.pdf when the save button is clicked.

Comment: You'd need to have server-side if you wish to make a new file...

Comment: So you want to save PDF file to local storage when doing `print()`? Is that correct?

Comment: @Justinas yes. I want to customize the save button function in print window so that I can save it in my local storage

Comment: @sj_abaquita This part is browser implementation that you can't change. Maybe implement your own save button. Just know that local storage has very limited size.